# My bash script does not find an existing file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, bash-scripting

I realized a bash script that works on an existing text file located into the same working directory of the script. The script take name of the file to compute through a function parameter.

The issue is that when I run the script it does not locate the file. I've already checked positional parameter of the function when called and the name of the file is correct. But a check on that filename "[ -e filename ]" or a command launched on it (ex. cat filename) returns an error. Filename not found.

I paste my script..

```
#!/bin/bash

query=
loan=

function count(){
  local valore=0
  local wordcmp
  TMPFILE=$(mktemp)

  if [ -n "$query" ]; then
    wordcmp=$query
  else wordcmp=$loan
  fi

  echo $1 (here print the correct file name passed by the caller)
  for FILE; do
    if [ -e $FILE ]; then
      cat $FILE | grep $wordcmp > $TMPFILE
      exec 3< $TMPFILE
  while read -u 3 line; do
    valore=$(($valore + ${line#$wordcmp}))
  done
      exec 3>&-
      echo "$wordcmp $valore"
      echo "Bye."
    else
      echo "$0: error --- log file $FILE not found" 1>&2
   fi
   valore=0
  done
}

set -- `getopt -o "h" -l "query,loan" -- "$@"`

while true; do

   case "$1" in

         --query) query=QUERY
              shift;;

         --loan) loan=LOAN
             shift;;

         -h) echo "$0: help" 1>&2
         echo "usage: $0 --query logfile for query summary" 1>&2
             echo "usage: $0 --loan logfile for loan summary" 1>&2
             echo "usage: $0 -h for this help message" 1>&2
         exit 1;;
         --) shift
break;;
 esac
done

if [ -z "$query" -a -z "$loan" ]; then
  echo "$0: you must specify at least one option and log file(s)" 1>&2
  echo "please type $0 -h for help" 1>&2
  exit 1
fi

if [ $# = 0 ]; then
  echo "$0: you must specify at least one log file" 1>&2
  echo "please type $0 -h for help" 1>&2
  exit 1
  shift
fi
 count $@
```

The output when invoking myscript --query filename.log is

"./myscript.sh: error --- log file 'filename.log' not found"

(but the file "filename.log" exist on the local directory when the script is launched)

Any Idea?

Thanks to all

Comment: did you try hard coding it to test?

Comment: Did you try using the -x switch to bash on line #1?  I do not see where FILE in the for loop of the count function is ever getting populated with a value.  Does $1 echo the --query so $2 should be filename.log?  Or is count only being called with a single parameter/argument?

Answer (score 3):

The error you say it gives ("./myscript.sh: error --- log file 'filename.log' not found") has single-quotes around the filename, but the command that prints it (`echo "$0: error --- log file $FILE not found" 1>&2`) didn't put them there. This suggests to me that they're part of the value of $FILE, meaning that it's looking for them as part of the actual file's name.

If I'm right about that, it's not a problem in the script, but in how you're calling it. So, how are you calling this script? If it's something like this:

```
cmd="./myscript.sh --loan 'filename.log'"
$cmd
```

...then that's the problem, because quoting in bash doesn't work that way; see [BashFAQ #050: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).